# What would the code below print? Java

Tags: java

This is a question from an assignment that I've been stuck on for a while now .I have to write down what the output of the program is, and i hope i can find some explanation to clear my confusion.

```
class Derp { 

    public int x;

    /* this method doesn't have any return type so the 
        program shouldn't even run? I get errors even when i 
        typed it netbeans. I decided to assume it was a 
        mistake made by the professor*/
    public Derp(int x) { 
      this.x=x; 
    }

    public String toString() {
      return new String("x=" + x);
    }
}

public class WhatsPrinted06 {

    public static void func(Derp d) {
      d.x++;  

    /* i don't think i've ever seen something like this, i tried 
        typing it in netbeans but i get an error. Is this another 
        way of writing d+=x;? It still shows an error 
        however*/
      System.out.println(d);
    }

    public static void main(String args[]) {
      Derp d1 = new Derp(10);
      func(d1);
    }
```

After going through this, I was thinking the professor might be trying to see if we can figure out when a program will run or not, however on other questions d.x++ keeps showing up, and she still didn't add a return type for public Derp{} in the other questions.

Comment: How about indenting your code properly if you are asking people to try and read it for you?

Comment: Why can't you just run it and see?

Comment: I tried running it but it fails

Comment: Then that's the result -- it fails. If you need further help, you might want to tell us how it fails for you.

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels
I get an error: Exception in thread "main" java.lang.RuntimeException: Uncompilable source code - non-static method derp(int x)

Comment: Then fix the compilation error, although the error message and your posted code don't seem to match up.

Comment: _"this method doesn't have a return type"_... It won't. It's a [constructor](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/constructors.html)!

Comment: and `d.x++;` is valid: field x is public in your `Derp` class. So this code is just adding one to the field of your `Derp` instance, hence the output would be 11.

Comment: oh ok thanks for the explanation

Answer (score 0):

The code obviously prints x=11.

The method without a return type is a constructor, i.e. a special method that is called when an object is instantiated.

Comment: The closing curly bracket ('}') is missing for your public class, it should go at the very end of the code, that's why it doesn't compile.